# How to pass data from WPF form to WPF usercontrol?

Tags: c#, wpf

I have Mainwindow.xaml (it's a form) some string pass to UserControl1.xaml (it's a usercontrol).

Comment: Your question is totally unclear. Can you clarify it? Please read [FAQ], [ask] and [help]

Comment: User control or another window?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1)You can create public property in UserControl like:

```
public string SomeString
{
get;
set;
}
```

And then pass string by xaml:

```
<UserControl1 SomeString="String"/>
```

or
bind SomeString property to property in your MainWindow

```
<UserControl1 SomeString="{Binding MyStr}"/>
```

2)You can pass your string to UserControl by constructor.

```
var uc = new UserControl(MyString);
```